# yandex maps 2 поддерживается IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer, yandex-maps-api

На сайте подключил карты яндекса, версии 2.1 (все сделал по документации). Так вот, ФФ, IE10 работает, а в IE8 никак не хочет - выскакивает окошка, с ошибкой примерно такого рода:

> Сведения об ошибке на веб-странице
>
> Агент пользователя: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1;
>   Win64; x64; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR
>   3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) штамп времени: Thu, 16 Apr 2015 05:47:43 UTC
>
> Сообщение: Требуется объект
>
> Строка: 613
>
> Символ: 4133
>
> Код: 0
>
> URI-код:
>   http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.23/release/combine.xml?modules=0a0-0*0b1n1a1o1b1c1d1p1e1r1g1h1i1k1l1v1m1x1_0c2l2m2n2i0e2C2D2E2F2G2B2I2k0d2w0f2L2M2S2T2U2V2W2X2Y2N202O212223242P252R27292$2-2_2!2*2(2)3g3h3i3k3m2,2q2j2z2Q2J3n3o3p3r2Z3a3b3s3v3w3x3t3u3c3y3d3e3f2.3B3A3C3D3E3F3H
>
> много кода ....
>
> GzHzIzKzPzRjRzMzNzOzSzTzUzVzXz0z1z3z2z4z5z6jSz7z8z9jEz$z_z.z!z*QaQcQiQdQkQlQeQfQgQhQmQnQoQpQrQsQtQAQCQHQI&jsonp_prefix=ymapsymaps2_1_23_loader

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

**Скажите , кто нибудь сталкивался таким, и как Вы решили проблему?**

**UPD**

```
**подключаю так:**
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Покажите как подключаете карту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В блоге Клуба API карт писали, что такое поведение бывает в IE 8 в Windows XP без установленных последних сервис-паков и обновлений. Связано с новой модульной системой modules, на которую перешел API карт в версии 2.
Вроде более дельного решения, чем установка последних обновлений, не предлагали.

Может, не стоит и заморачиваться? Новый API Яндекс.Карт поддерживает Microsoft Internet Explorer версий 8-10 только частично, а восьмерка - реальное старье.

Comment: конечно, печально все это.. спасибо за ответ